# Redactor Rails - unable to upload files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using redactor rails gem for providing the wysiwyg editor in my project. Whenever I run the application locally, the file upload seems to be working. But whenever I deploy and run the application on production, the File upload icon is not visible.

Wysiwyg editor in Local:

[image]

Wysiwyg editor in production:

[image]

In production environment, the File Upload icon is missing. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While calling redactor you are missing the file_upload attr. Please add this

```
 $('#redactor').redactor({
    fileUpload: '/your_file_upload_script/',
 });
```